# What is the correct sensor to use for capturing ambient noise?

Tags: sensor, microphone, sound

I'm working on a project to capture ambient noise in my room (e.g. coming from the nearby vehicles, birds, etc.) for audio analysis (understand loudness/frequency characteristics). Problem is I'm confused by the different types of mics/sound sensors. Which type is correct for such projects? The ones I'm looking at are:

- [ARCELI Electret Microphone Amplifier](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07MY293KD)
- [MAX4466 Electret Microphone Amplifier Module](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09MRTRR56)
- [Electret Condenser Microphone](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N0VMN9P)
- [INMP441 Omnidirectional Microphone](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09G4RNT3G)

Or should it be something different entirely?

Comment: What will you be using to analyze the sounds?

Comment: The type of mic really doesn't matter so much. Its directionality and frequency range should be akin to what you wish to measure. Some compensation of frequency response can be done on the recorded data later.

Comment: @BruceAbbott I was thinking of using something like librosa to analyse it offline on a computer.

Comment: @tobalt what prompt me to ask the question was I saw some remarks about some only capturing sound from sources a few inches from the mic. So, I was wondering if a normal mic can capture the sounds I hear from my window which are coming sometimes from 30 yards away.

Comment: If they have directionality comparable to an ear, then it is only a matter of amplification, unless the sounds are very quiet, then mic noise starts to matter eventually

Comment: `some only capturing sound from sources a few inches from the mic. ` That's a special type of dual mic, that captures the gradient, to reject background noises. It ought to be advertised as such. If you stick with 'normal' mics, you should be OK.

Comment: _"I was thinking of using something like librosa to analyse it offline on a computer"_- but how will you get it into the computer?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Oh, my plan is to use the mic with an ESP-01 and send it over WiFi.